# how to select the attribute that is dynamically created in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble with selecting the attribute of 'a' tag which is dynamically created.

```
<a id='comment_delete' comment_id='<%=comment.id %>'>delete</a>

...
...

$('#commentForm').submit(function(e){
    alert($('#comment_delete').last().attr('comment_id'));

...
```

What I want to do is that when I submit the commentForm, the new a tag with comment.id that has autoincrement attribute (in mysql) is created.

and also want to alert that new-created a tag`s comment.id

which has to be 40 since I`ve created 40 comments.

(comment.id is auto incrementing)

but that code above always alert 1.

and I cannot even understand what the outcome 1 is.

can anyone please explain why that code above is not working and how to solve?

any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: ID must be unique on document context. Here `$('#comment_delete')` only matches the first element with ID `comment_delete` (and so `.last()` as no meaning btw). You should use `class` instead. FYI, `comment_id` isn't valid HTML attribute, better would be to use `data-comment-id`

Comment: I was fool. thanks a lot, it works. give me an answer so I can adopt.

Comment: @A. Wolff 
is that invalid HTML attribute would be a problem..? since i`m using it for as expedient something like that?

Comment: @A. Wolff I came across another problem.. it works but since i`m creating comment and alert message with using ajax, it does not reflect the new comment.id until i refresh the page manually.. can you give me an advice once more?

Comment: You have to post relevant code regarding your issue in order to get any relevant answer

Comment: `id` relates to unique node, can you try it by changing it to class `<a class='comment_delete' ` and your function call like `alert($('.comment_delete').last()`

Comment: @A. Wolff since I cannot post newly because of time interval thing of stackoverflow, can I post my code to your email which is notified in your profile?

Comment: @Aswin Ramesh thanks for your help :)

Comment: @A. Wolff oh i figured it out.. thank you